# rpy2: handling nested data.tables from R

Tags: python, r, rpy2

I have R nested data.table of the format:

```
Date          Values
2019-10-11    <data.table>
2019-10-12    <data.table>
```

Each of the `Values` in the above data.table  are `<data.table>` are of the format:

```
Item     Inventory   Sales      Revenue
Clothing   100         50       100000
Auto       50          20       5000
```

So essentially, for the date `2019-10-11` the corresponding data.table holds the sales details.

I want to to be able to process this output and save it as independent pandas data frames.

Looking at the rpy2 documentation (https://rpy2.readthedocs.io/en/version_2.8.x/introduction.html#importing-packages) , one option appears to be to write a custom R function to process this and call it in python. But wondering if there is an easier way to take the R object and process it in python?
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Would documentation for the current rpy2 release answer this ?
https://rpy2.github.io/doc/v3.2.x/html/pandas.html